# Windows 10: False alert regarding KB2983588 (duplicate disk ID)?

Tags: windows-10, gpt

Windows 10 (1909 [Version 10.0.18363.535]) is very slow before the boot manager appears.
Then I find a reference to KB2983588 (saying I have duplicate disk IDs).

The text in German is: "*Der Datenträger "3" verfügt über dieselben Datenträger-IDs wie ein oder mehrere Datenträger, die mit dem System verbunden sind. Rufen Sie die Microsoft-Supportwebsite (http://support.microsoft.com) auf, und suchen Sie nach KB2983588, um das Problem zu beheben.*"
(Google-translated to: "*Disk "3" has the same disk IDs as one or more disks connected to the system. Go to the Microsoft support website (http://support.microsoft.com) and search for KB2983588 to resolve the problem.*")

However there are *no duplicate IDs* that I could find (Sorry German locale being used):

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Datenträger ###  Status         Größe    Frei     Dyn  GPT
  ---------------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Datenträger 0    Online         1863 GB   353 GB
  Datenträger 1    Online          931 GB   467 GB
  Datenträger 2    Online           64 TB      0 B        *
  Datenträger 3    Online         1023 GB      0 B        *

DISKPART> sel disk 0
Datenträger 0 ist jetzt der gewählte Datenträger.
DISKPART> uniqueid disk
Datenträger-ID: 6EC001A4
DISKPART> sel disk 1
Datenträger 1 ist jetzt der gewählte Datenträger.
DISKPART> uniqueid disk
Datenträger-ID: 6F20A1F4
DISKPART> sel disk 2
Datenträger 2 ist jetzt der gewählte Datenträger.
DISKPART> uniqueid disk
Datenträger-ID: {4BF4404B-D2F8-4C70-985B-20556843D8C4}
DISKPART> sel disk 3
Datenträger 3 ist jetzt der gewählte Datenträger.
DISKPART> uniqueid disk
Datenträger-ID: {EC9CD42E-3609-4625-A9CB-7A7C76DA7CC1}
```

I found one reference that the issue has to do with GPT partitions, but without giving details. Do you have any insights?

### Note:

I still see this message occasionally and it seems it has to do with my Drobo 5C (see https://www.drobo.com/storage-products/5C/) that has one normal drive (thin provisioned) and a backup drive (fully provisioned), both formatted by Drobo's tool (not Windows).
Maybe that formatting routine had an error.

So a related question could be:
How can I change the disk ID without causing any negative effects?

Comment: Your problem absolutely has nothing to do with KB2983588.  That update was released years ago

Comment: My problem may be absolutely unrelated to KB2983588, but the error message specifically refers to it.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be no solution at this stage. The most informative research I've seen is [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3c69bf50-5201-4aa4-95c5-212086906ef7/disk-ltngt-has-the-same-disk-identifiers-as-one-or-more-disks-connected-to-the-system) where a Seagate engineer is quoted:

> The issue seems to be related to BOT vs UAS. On new machines with UAS you get the same Unique ID, it appears to be handled by UPnP. There doesn't appear to be anything we can do about it. It appears to have something to do with the UAS driver as this does not happen when the same drives are connected via BOT. We would like to advise reaching out to Microsoft as well because this appears to be how the host bus handles Bulk Only Transport (BOT) and USB Attached SCSI (UAS) in Windows. The issue is not seen when connected to a host via BOT and is only seen when connected via UAS. So it appears to be dependent on the hosts bus and some underlying logic of the bus in Windows. It is something that Seagate cannot control